# validates_uniqueness_of field scoped to a has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one, validates-uniqueness-of

I have the following models:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course                                                          
  has_one :term, :through => :course
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :term
  has_many :sections
end

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :sections, :through => :courses
end
```

I would like to be able to do the following in my `Section` model (`call_number` is a field in `Section`):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :call_number, :scope => :term_id
```

This obviously doesn't work because `Section` doesn't have `term_id`, **so how can I limit the scope to a relationship's model?**

I tried creating a custom validator for `Section` to no avail (doesn't work when I create a new `Section` with the error *"undefined method 'sections' for nil:NilClass"*):

```
def validate_call_number
  if self.term.sections.all(:conditions => ["call_number = ? AND sections.id <> ?", self.call_number, self.id]).count > 0
    self.errors[:base] << "Call number exists for term"
    false
  end
  true
end
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your validation code is correct, why don't you simply add a check for term existence?

```
def validate_call_number
  return true if self.term.nil? # add this line
  if self.term.sections.all(:conditions => ["call_number = ? AND sections.id <> ?", self.call_number, self.id]).count > 0
    self.errors[:base] << "Call number exists for term"
    false
  end
  true
end
```

Comment: `term` always seems to be `nil` before a save.  I think it is because `term` is only available to the `section` through a relationship.

Comment: @zsalzbank it should depends whether you've assigned a `Course` to that section. If you've assigned a `Course` to `Section` and that `Course` has a `Term` `self.term` should not be nil even if the section instance is a new record.